# Query with data from cell in excel in data connection

Tags: sql, excel, dynamics-crm-2011, database-connection

I have an excel sheets that imports large amount of data from microsoft dynamics. I use the export function in crm, and only imports data with "owner equals current user". Somethimes I also need the sheet to import other users data, but have issues in changing the sql import code.

today it looks like this:

```
join FilteredAccount as "af" on ("ac".col_accountid  =  "af".accountid and ("af".ownerid = ? and "af".customertypecode = 181400001)) order by  "col_holding0".col_financialproductidname asc , "col_holding0".col_holdingid asc
```

The questionmark in the code after "af".ownerid = ? is where i want the query to use a value from cell C2 in sheet29 (sheetsname is admin, so I assume something like admin!c2), but i get an error that it cant find this value. I have also used "sheet29!c2" with the same result.
How do I make this query use the value in cell sheet29!c2 in excel?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is this query in VBA code, or in a Get External Data query?

Comment: This is Get External Data Query.

Comment: No replies so far... anyone?